# Tapfortap frequent requests in my logfile

Tags: android

In the adb logcat I see this , even when the all the apps are closed, and the screen is turned off. Can someone tall me why tapfortap doesn't stop sending requests when the application is closed ?

```
10-16 10:09:19.874 D/com.tapfortap.TapForTap( 1692): has checked in? true
10-16 10:09:19.904 D/com.tapfortap.TapForTap( 1692): has checked in? true
10-16 10:09:19.973 D/com.tapfortap.TapForTap( 1692): has checked in? true
10-16 10:09:20.154 D/com.tapfortap.TapForTap( 1692): has checked in? true
10-16 10:09:20.204 D/com.tapfortap.TapForTap( 1692): has checked in? true
10-16 10:09:20.263 D/com.tapfortap.TapForTap( 1692): has checked in? true
10-16 10:09:20.294 D/com.tapfortap.TapForTap( 1692): has checked in? true
10-16 10:09:20.344 D/com.tapfortap.TapForTap( 1692): has checked in? true
10-16 10:09:20.384 D/com.tapfortap.TapForTap( 1692): has checked in? true
10-16 10:09:20.443 D/com.tapfortap.TapForTap( 1692): has checked in? true
10-16 10:09:20.524 D/com.tapfortap.TapForTap( 1692): has checked in? true
10-16 10:09:20.563 D/com.tapfortap.TapForTap( 1692): has checked in? true
```

Comment: don't understand the title ...

Answer (score 1):

These are debugging log messages. If you use a recent version of Tap for Tap or filter the log to not show debugging info then you will not see this in the log. One reason it may be so frequent is that someone is trying to request ads in a loop. The SDK on its on certainly does not call that method several times a second!

source: I am the lead developer at Tap for Tap.

Comment: okey I understand that someone might request more times, but I do not understand why after I close the app or I turn off the screen the tapfortap is still sending requests ?, why the tapfortap service keeps drain my battery even when I close all of the activities and I turn the screen off ?

Answer (score 0):

TapForTap probably is a service. It is asking whether it has checked in or not.

Comment: But it checks 3 to 5 times in one second  . . .

Comment: @Lukap You should try to find the application in question in Application Manager and Force Stop it. Also have a check in Running Applications to make sure its not running.